# Excel VBA loop module sheet out of range?

Tags: vba, excel

I am encountering a runtime error 1004 "Select method of Range class failed" on a script I have running within a module. The script is tied to a button on a different sheet. When run, the script is meant to look at the N column of the sheet "projects overview," find any rows containing the value "Complete - Design" and copies the values of that row to a temporary holding row on sheet3. From that point, the row is added to a third and final sheet (sheet9) where it's inserted into a running list of other rows that have been copied. The original row on the "projects overview" sheet is then deleted.

I get the error when the script reaches the Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").Select part of the code. I feel like it has something to do with activating the sheet from within this module because the rest of the script is enveloped in a with statement that targets the projects overview sheet, but I don't know how to resolve that conflict. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub CompleteJob()

Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim LrowProjectsOverview As Long

    With Sheets("Projects Overview")
        .Select

        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        For LrowProjectsOverview = lastRow To Firstrow Step -1
            With .Cells(LrowProjectsOverview, "N")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    If .Value = "Complete - Design" Then .EntireRow.Copy

                    Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").Select

                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False


                        If Sheet9.Range("B2").Value = "" Then
                            Sheet9.Range("A2:Q2").Value = Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").Value
                            Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").ClearContents

                            Else

                            Sheet9.Range("B2").EntireRow.Insert
                            Sheet9.Range("A2:Q2").Value = Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").Value
                            Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").ClearContents
                            Sheet9.Range("B2:Q2").Interior.Color = xlNone
                            Sheet9.Range("B2:Q2").Font.Bold = False
                            Sheet9.Range("B2:Q2").Font.Color = vbBlack
                            Sheet9.Range("B2:Q2").RowHeight = 14.25

                        End If

                        If Sheet9.Range("B2").Value = "" Then
                           Sheet9.Range("B2").EntireRow.Delete

                        End If

                    If .Value = "Complete - Design" Then .EntireRow.Delete

                End If
            End With
        Next LrowProjectsOverview
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't `Select` a range on a non-active sheet.  The question is ... why would you want to?  `Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").Select` `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False` is equivalent to `Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False` so there is no need to `Select` anything.  Please have a read of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/6535336)

Comment: Having said that though, I doubt whether you will be able to paste an entire row (if `.Value = "Complete - Design"`, or nothing otherwise) into 17 cells.